# Show property for a real valued function $f:\mathbb{R^n}-\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying certain constraint

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have been trying to prove that given a function $f$ as above, where $$x\cdot \nabla f(x)=0$$ for all $x \not=0$, we have $f(x)=f(tx)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $t>0$.

My approach was initially to sub in $tx$ for $x$ and by the given constraint try and deduce something. I also thought about using the multivariable chain rule by defining a new function $g(x)=tx$, but not sure how that will help as we have a condition based on grad f evaluated at $tx$, which is different (I think) from grad of $f \circ g$ evaluated at $x$. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** For any fixed $x\in\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$, consider the function
$$g(t)=f(tx),\qquad t>0.$$
Prove that $g’\equiv0$, hence $g$ is a constant and then $g(t)=g(1)$ for all $t>0$.

Proof of $g’\equiv0$:

> We have $$g’(t)=x\cdot(\nabla f)(tx)=\frac1t[tx\cdot(\nabla f)(tx)]=0$$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: Sorry if this reveals part of the spoiler - is it really necessary to add $\frac 1t$ and $t$ at the front since the dot product of $x$ and the gradient is already assumed to be $0$? Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @AlgTop1854 Maybe it is not a serious problem. The condition $x\cdot\nabla f(x)=0$ is converted into $F(x)=0$ in my head with $F(x)=x\cdot \nabla f(x)$. Then, $x\cdot(\nabla f)(tx)=\frac1t F(tx)=0$. So, I think it is necessary to add this $1/t$ at the front. Nevertheless, you’re free to skip this step and directly get $g’(t)=0$, which is perfectly acceptable to me.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.  I think it's just making clearer that it is happening at $tx$.  Since such functions can only be constant, you can't really work it through in an explicit example.